# Redmi 4 just switched off

Tags: fastboot, redmi

I have redmi 4 which was working fine. But it is now switched off. When tried to switch on it shows mi logo then android logo and again switch off. It is bootloader is locked, non rooted and usb debugging not enabled. So not able to connect via adb to computer. But only able to reach fastboot and recovery. And when conneted to computer via usb and fastboot via command prompt detects and shows the serial number. I'm tring to do something in short. Otherwise flashing twrp and then os again is long route; tried but in vain. As well as tried some YouTube,Google,Chinese Mi software too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: bootloader unlocked?

Comment: No bootloader is locked

Comment: you can't flash TWRP on locked bootloader. *'fastboot oem edl'* should reboot phone in EDL mode. install Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 Driver and flash [ROM](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/prada) with MiFlash. if still not working the emmc is weared out and device is end of life

Comment: Tried `fastboot oem edl`  response is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot oem edl
...
**FAILED** (remote: device locked, oem edl is not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.010s`

Comment: use deep flash cable or try modified Fastboot_edl-v2.zip or use [test point](https://xdarom.com/xiaomi-test-point) method

Comment: so you did flash in EDL mode?